# java OOP and array required

Tags: java, oop, matrix

I'm beginning Java OOP and i'm doing an exercise about creating a class `Matrix` that can do operations like `sum()`.

I wrote the code below but in the method `add()` there is a problem. When I compile the code this error appears on the screen:

```
Matrix.java:98: error: array required, but Matrix found
                                result[i][j] = this[i][j] + b[i][j];
                                      ^
Matrix.java:98: error: array required, but Matrix found
                                result[i][j] = this[i][j] + b[i][j];
                                                   ^
Matrix.java:98: error: array required, but Matrix found
                                result[i][j] = this[i][j] + b[i][j];
```

How can I fix the error? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix{

    int[][] mat;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;

    public Matrix(int l,int m, int n){
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
        mat = new int[m][n];

        for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
                mat[i][j] = l;
            }
        }

    }
    public Matrix(int m, int n){
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
        mat = new int[m][n];
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < m; ++i){
            for(j = 0; j < n; ++j){
                int c = i + 1;
                int b = j + 1;
                System.out.print("inserire m[" + c + "][" + b + "]: ");
                mat[i][j] = tastiera.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }


    }

    public void set(int i, int j){
        assert (i - 1 <= m):
        "Errore, l'indice i deve essere al piu': " + m;
        assert (j - 1<= n):
        "Errore, l'indice j deve essere al piu': " + n;

        int c = i + 1;
        int b = j + 1;
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("inserire il numero m[" + c + "][" + b + "]: ");
        mat[i - 1][j - 1] = tastiera.nextInt();


    }

    public int get(int i, int j){

        return mat[i - 1][j - 1];

    }

    public void stampa(){
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < mat.length; ++i){
            for(j = 0; j < mat[i].length; ++j){ 
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public int rows(){
        return this.m;
    }

    public int columns(){
        return this.n;
    }

    public Matrix add(Matrix b){
        Matrix result = new Matrix(0,this.m, this.n);
        assert(this.m != b.m):
        "Errore dimensioni delle righe";
        assert(this.n != b.n):
        "Errore dimensioni delle colonne";

        for (int i = 0; i < this.m; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < this.n; ++j){
                result[i][j] = this[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

//P.S. thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to your method add is of type Matrix. What you need is the two dimensional array. You have to change it to something like below.

```
        result.mat[i][j] = this.mat[i][j] + b.mat[i][j];
```